# How to apply a function to a DataFrame column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below in Spark. it works great. I just wondered how I would run functions in the same way on a Spark dataframe. I know I can use Lambda for the below, I just wanted to see if I could run larger functions (and how)

```
def printline(x):
    return x*2

#The map function creates a new RDD with 1 to 1 mapping from the old
rdd3= rdd2.map(printline)
rdd3.take(5)
```

So if I have the same in a dataframe and I wanted to call a custom function to carry out an operation on a specific field, how would I do that?

```
df = my_spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "false").load(r"c:\Users\kiera\Downloads\fakefriends.csv")

#Rename columns to make them easier to work with
df = df.withColumnRenamed('_c0', 'UserID')\
        .withColumnRenamed('_c1', 'Name')\
        .withColumnRenamed('_c2', 'Age')\
        .withColumnRenamed('_c3', 'Friends')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printline` is a Python function.

RDD API is a low-level API for Spark developers and that's why it's often easier to reason about a Spark application that uses RDD API. That's Spark Core.

DataFrame API is a high-level API for Spark developers who think in terms of SQL (data engineers?) That's Spark SQL (that is built atop Spark Core).

The question is how to enrich the standard functions available in Spark SQL for something very similar to RDD API. That's **user-defined functions** (UDFs).

---

The following is to express applying `printline` function to every row (record) in `rdd2` (that's to be as close to Python's pandas and Scala's Collection API as possible).

```
rdd3= rdd2.map(printline)
rdd3.take(5)
```

The equivalent is to use a user-defined function and `DataFrame.withColumn` operator. They're the same.

A pseudo-code would look as follows:

```
df3 = df2.withColumn("nameOfTheColumn", printlineUDF(comma-separated column names))
df3.take(5)
```

Note that you work with `Row`s in DataFrame API while in RDD API objects are of your type.